# How to improve this graph with multiple lines in ggplo2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Example dataframe: [datafame.RData](https://prequest.websiteseguro.com/ftp/)

I would like to create a chart below with these automated interactions. Ex. Changing the variable the average calculations are automatically remade and changed in the graph. For example Pais 'n' presents NA.

Here is an example of the expected chat in the output of ggplo2.
[image: output example]

What I managed to do in R was this:

```
mydata %>% 
  dplyr::filter(Region %in% 'World  median') %>%
  dplyr::select(year,value) %>% 
  ggplot() +
    aes(year,value, group=1,color="World median")+
  geom_line()+
  geom_line(data=mydata %>% 
              dplyr::filter(Country %in% 'Canada') %>%
              dplyr::select(year,value),
            aes(year, value, group=1, color="Canada"))+
  geom_line(data=mydata %>% 
              dplyr::filter(Country %in% 'Brazil') %>%
              dplyr::select(year,value),
            aes(year, value, group=1, color="Brazil"))
```

The result was the one below. But if you have any suggestions on how to do better using ggplot I appreciate it.
[image: result obtained]

Comment: What do you mean by "do better"? What would like you like see?

Comment: @phalteman, Thanks for the feedback, correct the doubt and the title.